# getting news from DB

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql

```
public partial class newsarticle : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int article_id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);

            string select = "SELECT [ID],[NEWS],[CONTENTS] FROM [NEWS]";
            string strCon = System.Web
                      .Configuration
                      .WebConfigurationManager
                      .ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"]
                      .ConnectionString;

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strCon);
            conn.ConnectionString = strCon;
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(select, conn);
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                news_title.Text = myReader["NEWS"].ToString();
                news_content.Text = myReader["CONTENTS"].ToString();

            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

hello,  i have problem with this method. I connected these  "news" and "contents" from DB with news_title and news_content, and in newsarticle.aspx site i have two literal controls which writes news and content. And i have

```
<a href="/newsarticle.aspx?id=<%#Eval("ID") %>"> 
   <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("News") %>'>
   </asp:Label>
</a>
```

, 
with this I get links of news name and when I click on one the link it always returns me last name and contentfrom table. exmp. if i have 4 liks and when i click on 2 i get result from 4 link.
Naybody know what could be solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not added `article_id` in your select statement's where clause.

```
string select = "SELECT [ID],[NEWS],[CONTENTS] FROM [NEWS] where ID = " + article_id.ToString();
```

Comment: Can you debug, and check whether you are getting id here   int article_id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]); you need to check this variable in debug mode article_id

Comment: here is my skype id  toakhtar  ,  add me and then I will see u the problem and try to resolve